# Trying to organize images and text into a sort of order form

Tags: html, css, image

This isn't actually an order form (as yet) but I think that best describes it.  I want to create a grid of 3 images inline, then text below each, then repeat indefinitely.  I tried turning each row into a unique table but alignment became a problem. Then I tried making one table and giving the image and text < tr >'s unique classes, but I'm having trouble getting the height of the text rows to shrink to a more aesthetically pleasing size, and also centering the text below the image.  I tried to do this artificially with as many "& nbsp's" as was appropriate, but then the text started wrapping onto a new line and it messed all that up. Code and link to js fiddle below:

```
<table id="saladGrid">
   <tr class="saladPics">
    <td id="one"></td>
    <td id="two"></td>
    <td id="three"></td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="saladText">
    <td class="text"><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; acorn squash, golden beets, pistachios</p></td>
    <td class="text"><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; roasted eggplant, herbed ricotta, sumac</p></td>
    <td class="text"><p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; arugula, fennel, blackberries, quinoa, pickled shallots</p></td>
   </tr>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jshweky/5bTW8/

(On a side note, I'm new to stackoverload so if there's any protocol I'm not following with respect to posting, I'd be grateful for any tips/suggestions. Thanks!)

Comment: Center the text using text-align:center; on your text class That way you will have the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this: **http://jsfiddle.net/EX9f9/**

If you have a look at the code below you'll notice a couple of things:

**HTML**

```
<table id="saladGrid">
    <tr class="saladPics">
        <td class="s1"></td> //I changed your classes 'one','two',etc
        <td class="s2"></td>
        <td class="s3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="saladTxt">
        <td class="txt"><p>acorn squash, golden beets, pistachios</p></td>
        <td class="txt"><p>roasted eggplant, herbed ricotta, sumac</p></td>
        <td class="txt"><p>arugula, fennel, blackberries, quinoa, pickled shallots</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- In your HTML I changed your `id`'s `one`, `two`, etc to classes consisting of the same word/letter, only a different number, for better readability. (Those could also be ID's btw, the main point is the use of equal terms with only one differentiator)

---

**CSS**

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
td {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#saladGrid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
}
#saladGrid table {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-spacing: 30px;
}
.saladPics td {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 350px 350px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.saladPics td.s1 {background-image:url("http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a514/jshweky/Gourmade%20to%20Order/IMG_1989_zps38d802a7.jpg");}
.saladPics td.s2 {background-image:url("http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a514/jshweky/Gourmade%20to%20Order/IMG_1483_zpsc4ca87cf.jpg");}
.saladPics td.s3 {background-image:url("http://i1281.photobucket.com/albums/a514/jshweky/Gourmade%20to%20Order/IMG_1992_zps1b881869.jpg");}
```

- In your CSS I removed all the repeated declarations and put them together in one overlapping class. Now, only the background-image has a separate rule for every separate element.
- I removed a couple of rules you don't need (and probably added in an failed attempt to style the table to your liking).
- At the start I added two rules: `table` and `td`. Those are two general classes I always put at the start of my CSS, it's alright if you overwrite some of it later by other rules, these just ensure that the browser doesn't doe any funky business.
- I put the whole table in a `div`, to show you how to contain the size of a table (but notice that the height is still more than the `400px` I gave it).
- **Notice the `text-align:center;` and `vertical-align: middle;` in the `td` rule. These alight your text horizontally and vertically.** (The answer to your main question)
- **IMPORTANT**: `vertical-align:middle;` only works on tables, no other elements. Keep that in mind!

---

About your first problem:
*"...trouble getting the height of the text rows to shrink to a more aesthetically pleasing size..."*

This is unfortunately a property of the table: it will form itself to the content and the space it has on the page. It will fill every inch it gets and will automatically stretch to fit the content. You CAN NOT (as far as I know) limit the size of one row of a table.

Only solution would be to put the table in a div and limit the height of the div so that the whole table gets squished together, and even then I couldn't tell you for sure how the table will behave.. you push it in a tiny corner, there's no telling what it will do:)